# How to install packages offline?

Tags: centos, yum, centos7

Our server runs offline and we need to install lot of yum packages, like oracle-jdk, elasticsearch, nginx, etc.

Is there any way to download the rpm dependencies so we can install them offline in the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintain a local CentOS mirror on an Internet-connected machine with `rsync` to a public CentOS mirror that accepts rsync connections. You can then copy these directories to a USB stick and use them as installation sources. They already carry the necessary metadata to act as repositories, so you only need to point the installer at them.

```
$ du -sh /srv/www/mirrors/centos/7.1.1503/{os,updates}/x86_64 
7.1G    /srv/www/mirrors/centos/7.1.1503/os/x86_64
2.1G    /srv/www/mirrors/centos/7.1.1503/updates/x86_64
```

In the case of third party packages, you can also mirror those yourself using the `reposync` command line tool, which downloads the contents of yum repositories to a local filesystem, and `createrepo`, which creates a yum repository out of a set of RPMs in a directory.

Remember that repositories do not have to be on the network. They can be located on a local filesystem such as a hard drive, DVD-ROM or USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for a local repository, take a look to this [article](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalMirror) or [this one](http://www.unixmen.com/setup-local-yum-repository-centos-7/)

Comment: Nop, I want something like, downloading all the rpm of the packages and its dependencies in a Centos 7.1 machine with internet connection and then move all this rpm files (using a pendrive, for example) to the server and install them there.

Comment: Ok, you want a local repository just for the extra packages you need to install. That's right?

Comment: But the server is totally isolated, is not able to connect to a local repository on its LAN. Thanks.

Comment: A local repository can also be a repository hold in the FileSystem. If you have another box with the same OS installed perhaps you can issue a `yum install pkg`, normally it prompts you if you want to download and install the package and its dependencies. Perhaps you can download all needed files and make a local repository with those packages. Or perhaps some other user can give you a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

> I want something like downloading all RPM packages and dependencies in another Centos 7.1 machine with internet connection and then move all those RPM files (using a pendrive, for example) to the server and install them there.

That sounds like something fairly trivial by [setting the option](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-working_with_yum_cache) `keepcache=0` to `keepcache=1` in [`yum.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf) on the online CentOS server. First install there all packages you want to install on your offline server as well and then simply copy the collected RPM packages from the various `/var/cache/yum/*/*/*packages/` directories.

Answer (score 0):

`yum install -y xxx yyy --downloadonly`

then all the rpms will be downloaded to `/var/cache/yum`.

Comment: It was not written down explicitly, but I think the packages would be transferred offline to the system. What this command downloads is the packages you need on the source system, not on the destination one.